# Exclude Test Classes in dependend Maven JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, ear

We have an EAR Project which assembles a WAR File and has some JAR Files as dependency. POM.xml of the EAR looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>our.package</groupId>
            <artifactId>package-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.ear.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>5</version>
                    <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>de.project</groupId>
                            <artifactId>project.war</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                            <bundleFileName>project.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>project</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The package-impl, which is included in the EAR as JAR, has some Test Classes in it. Unfortunatly these Test Classes are bundled whith the JAR, when the EAR is assembled. Besides the facet, that Maven should inlucde the test classe, how can I exclude these Test classes in the JAR, when the EAR is assembled?

All Test Classes in package-impl are in src/test/java Source Folder.

Regards
Sven

**UPDATE:**
When I build the package-impl indepent from tha EAR manually the test classes are not included (as expected).

**UPDATE2**

Here is the complete package-impl POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>project-impl</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../project</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>${jee6.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.jpa-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-vfs</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss-vfs.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- depenencies on third party modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.solder</groupId>
            <artifactId>solder-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.solder.solder-impl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>seam-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jboss.seam-persistence.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- already provided by jboss as -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.richfaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.richfaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>${org.reflections.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**UPDATE3**

This ended up to be an eclipse setting. The EAR-Project had a list of folders which contained the test folder.

Comment: What does it mean jar has test classes inside? It shouldn't. There should be only compiled main classes inside. Is this `package-impl` artifact also build by Maven?

Comment: If you have test classes inside a EAR/JAR than you are not using the defaults. There is something strange in your configuration. usually in the jar no test classes will be packaged into.

Comment: @Michal Kalinowski
The package-impl has TestCases which are (for some reason) compiled as java classes and packed into the package-impl JAR which is a dependent of the EAR Project. And yes, the package-impl is also build with Maven.

Comment: OK, so give us that `package-impl` module's POM. I'm 99% sure that it has some kind of weird and hacky POM that include somehow test classes into main artifact. Usually, if you need to deploy compiled test classes and use the standard way of doing this, there is a separate artifact of `test-jar` type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to be in the module for the dependent JAR file.  A perhaps someone has configured the build to include the test classes in the JAR.  If so, you should fix the module (i.e. its POM file) to not do this, rather than trying to deal with it in your EAR module.

Comment: There is no special configuration in the POM.xml of the package-impl. However, I did try out the compiler- and jar-plugin to exclude all test-classes, but it did not work.

Comment: Nevertheless, the problem IS in that area.  A "normal" Maven-build JAR file built in the "normal way" does not contain the test classes.  Did you try building the dependent JAR yourself?

Comment: Yes, I build the JAR independet from the EAR and the comiled test classes are not includes. Just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have accidentally put Test classes in src/main/java instead of src/test/java, and this works(compiles, runs) in eclipse but fails my build because JUnit is not in the class path for the build.
May or may not be true in your case but worth checking.